# Apache Spark: map-side aggregation vs in-map combiner

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, scalability

I'm currently migrating from the Hadoop MR paradigm to apache Spark, and there is  a few doubts that come to my mind regarding advanced efficiency implementation patterns outside the usual "map and reduce" basic workflow.

In this well known book [(Lin and Dier 2010)](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/) the "in-mapper combiner" pattern is introduced, which can significantly improve efficiency in many applications.

i.e, the canonical word count example in hadoop, where we normally emit (word, 1) tuples to be further combined, can be greatly improved if local aggregation of (word, n) tuples is performed and then emitted. Although combiners can fulfil this behaviour my experience is that using local variables for each mapper along with hadoop's functions like "setUp" and "cleanUp" can lead to higher computational savings (here is a nice [tutorial](https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/the-in-mapper-combining-design-pattern-for-mapreduce-programming/)).

Inside the Spark world I could not find anything similar, just the so called map-side aggregation, which is equivalent to the Hadoop's local combiner. Given the previous example, I wonder if it can be translated into Spark by using map functions.

Comment: _map-side aggregation, which is equivalent to the Hadoop's local combiner_ - as far as I can tell it is not exactly true. If you take a look at the `Aggregator` source, and further at the `ExternalAppendOnlyMap` data is aggregated conterminously as long as there is enough memory. So transformations like `aggregateByKey` / `combineByKey` should give you what you need. If prefer more explicit approach you can `mapPartitions` and aggregate the results.

Comment: I see your point. 
Looking at the source and I've noticed the differences you mention with the basic MR in hadoop. 
However I think that the only solution here might be using `mapPartitions` because my problem generates a large number of <k,v> pairs from each element (line) in the RDD and the combination of them is associative and commutative, so reduce is fine. As in the wordCount example, the map operation is emitting pairs with unary values <word, 1> that could be simplified by emitting them once from the partition.

I'll try to benchmark the options and post the results if I find the time.

Comment: There should be no significant difference compared to `aggregateByKey` especially when you use mutable buffers.